# How best can I define ENV Variables in a Rack based app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, minitest, roda

I am playing with RODA by Jeremy Evans https://roda.jeremyevans.net/. However, I am having issues setting Environment Variable for my Test_Environment.

**config/initializers/contenful_model.rb**

```
ContentfulModel.configure do |config|
  config.space = ENV.fetch('CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID')
  config.access_token = ENV.fetch('CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN')
  config.environment = "master"
end
```

**.env.rb**

```
case ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development'
when 'test'
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID'] ='key-here'
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN'] =''
when 'production'
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID'] ='key-here'
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN'] ='key-here'
else
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID'] ='key-here'
  ENV['CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN'] ='key-here'
end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"
require_relative '../../models/recipe'
require_relative '../../config/initializers/contentful_model'

require_relative '../minitest_helper'
```

It worked well for development, however, the config in the initializers is not available in the Test environment. I am currently hardcoding those credentials inside **spec/spec_helper.rb** which doesn't make sense to expose them. I did set ENV variables for Test RACK_ENV in my **.env.rb** file but it is not reachable from my test environment. **How can I get the env variables available to test env??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only problem is that I am not loading the `.env.rb` file inside the spec helper directory. So solving it for me was to require `.env.rb` file in my `spec_helper.rb` and it worked.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require_relative '../../.env.rb'
```